# Workflow to generate an email to 'Created by' based on a Status

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I'm working with a Sharepoint list, where there are three tiers of users. 
1 - Initiator
2 - Reviewer
3 - Approver

when approver takes approval action, the list signifies that the case is Closed. I'd like to generate an automated email back to 'Initiator' stating that case has been resolved.

furthermore, there are actions and additional documents that get added to cases by reviewer and approver, which the initiator can not see.

Is it possible to create a .pdf/or print screen view and attach it to the auto generated email for Initiator to see.

Hope that wasn't too confusing!

Comment: why not just trigger email to initiator through designer workflow , once case is closed? attaching email seems overkill for simple solution. Do you want initiator to visit the list after they submit?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no OOB method to achieve your requirement.

There is no workflow action to generate the pdf/print screen view. And we cannot send emails with attachments in the designer workflow.

And you could consider developing Visual Studio workflow or use third-party solutions to achieve your requirement.

More references:

[SharePoint 2010 - Send Email With Attachment Workflow Activity.](http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/releases/view/66258)

[Workflows in SharePoint 2013 using Visual Studio.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1071020/%2FArticles%2F1071020%2FWorkflows-in-SharePoint-using-Visual-Studio)